# Can I still travel to Sweden only with a national ID?

Tags: schengen, europe, sweden, greek-citizens

I am going to Sweden for a week, taking this route:

```
 Greece ->(flight)-> Austria ->(flight)-> Denmark ->(train)-> Sweden
```

I read on a news site that Sweden has issues with Schengen and would probably stop accepting travelers without passport. Since Greece, Austria and Denmark are in Schengen, my only concern is Sweden. Will I have any problems?

I am a Greek citizen.

Comment: It's important to note that **a driver's license is not a national ID**, I know that there is some confusion about these in Sweden given that most places accept your driver's license. You can read more about them and the differences [in Swedish](https://polisen.se/Service/Pass-och-id-kort/Fakta-om-pass-och-nationellt-id-kort/) or [in English](http://polisen.se/en/Languages/Service/Passport-and-national-ID-card/) Can't add this as a comment because of low reputation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45653/discussion-on-question-by-tasos-can-i-still-travel-to-sweden-only-with-a-nationa).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the Swedish police, there are temporary border controls, but that does not change the list of documents you can use to cross the border:

> ## Swedish nationals or nationals of other Nordic countries
>
> You do not need a passport or national ID card, but you must prove that you are a national of a Nordic country by means of a driver’s license, for example.
>
> ## Nationals of non-Nordic countries
>
> You need a passport or an ID card. A national ID card is an ID card issued by the competent authority in each EU Member State. If you have a residence permit in an EU Member State, you need to prove both your identity and your residence permit.

Source: https://polisen.se/en/Languages/Laws-and-Regulations/Temporary-border-controls/

Comment: _"by the competent authority"_ ...is there also an incompetent authority?

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Nope, but there is competent non-authority (forgers).

Comment: Funny part is driving licences don't display nationality, meaning the police check those against the people registry. It's far less of a hassle to show a passport or national ID Card even as a Nordic citizen

Comment: @Alexander I rather think it's just a more concise way of saying "...by whichever authority is charged with the task of issuing national IDs..."

Comment: @Crazydre Of the Nordic countries, only Sweden and Denmark issue (optional) national id cards. Since the freedom of movement for Nordic citizens between the Nordic states is regulated by the Nordic Passport Union agreement, which predates the Schengen membership by some 50 years, Swedish authorities are not allowed to require Nordic citizens to present any kind of id to enter Sweden. Speaking one of the Nordic languages, having pale skin, blond hair and freckles should be sufficient documentation of the right to enter.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Zlatan Ibrahimovic? Mads Mikkelsen?  Or how would a naturalized citizen who speaks with a foreign accent document a right to enter?

Comment: @phoog I don't work for the immigration police, so I am not able to tell you how they do their work.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Sweden and Finland, not Denmark. Like I said, you can use a driving licence, but they may very well check it against the registries to establish your nationality unless, as you said, you're obviously Nordic

Comment: @Crazydre You are right, only Sweden and Finland.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo indeed.  We in the US have a similar problem with inland border patrol checkpoints.  But our population being perhaps more diverse in appearance and language, the problem likely manifests itself differently here.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes

As long as Sweden is in the EU it should be possible to visit it with only a national ID. In my experience in other Schengen countries when you fly between them you don't even go through a passport check.

If you are not a citizen of a country that is part of the EU you need have a passport with you although it might not be checked during your stay.

Comment: It's also possible for EU citizens to visit non-Schengen EU countries with just an ID.  It's more about Sweden's membership in the EU than in the Schengen system.

Comment: And it is all EU countries, not just the Schengen countries, and an official ID card is acceptable, it does not need to be a passport.

Comment: @phoog As well as the CEFTA states, Georgia and overseas French territories, among others

Answer (score 2):

Sweden is — just like Denmark, Austria and Greece — a member of the Schengen treaty.
Furthermore, Sweden is a member state of the European Union.

The first says that there are to be no systematic identity checks when entering Sweden from another Schengen member state (in this case: Denmark). This rule is partly waived due to the large number of migrants that entered last autumn (I don’t know when the ID checks will be lifted again) so upon entering Sweden by rail or road from Copenhagen you will be asked to show ID.

However, the second also grants you freedom of movement, as you are also an EU national. Furthermore, EU treaties clearly state that a national ID card is a valid ID document for crossing EU borders; a passport is not required except for citizens of those countries that do not issue national ID cards (most notably the UK). Sweden has no right to disallow you entering the country except if you pose a national threat of some sort (i.e. intelligence suggests you are a terrorist — very unlikely). Most importantly, Sweden cannot reject you for travelling on a national ID card rather than a passport.

Technically, both could change. The UK example shows how difficult it is to change the second condition. While exiting the Schengen agreement permanently may be easier, you are still entitled to travel to an EU country (such as Ireland, which is non-Schengen) using only your national ID card until the second condition is moot.

---

On a technicality note, Sweden requires the train operating company to make sure all their travellers have valid documents before letting them board — this is akin to what countries request from airlines. Therefore, before boarding an Øresundståg, you will be asked by train staff to show a valid ID document. The *actual* border controls will be performed by Swedish police in Hyllie, the first stop after having crossed the Öresund bridge.

Comment: (+1) Following the introduction of the Irish passport card, there are exactly two EU countries that do not issue national ID cards: The UK and Denmark.

Comment: @Relaxed I wasn’t sure enough on Denmark, but for 2 years + *x*, UK will still be a valid example ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a residence permit from one of the Schengen zone countries , I think you won´t have any problems but you can stay only for less then 90 days.
But if you have only a visa for like 3 months then it is better to check because sometimes you are restricted. 
And if you are a citizen from an EU country then the question should not be even asked , you can go to Sweden with no problem.